# figuring out a weird delimiter in python

Tags: python

I have data in a text file in the following form:

```
371012200010401^A218032263303^A2011-09-27^A10:26:04.000^A75.00^A1^A0^A
371010032020101^A792392400085^A2011-09-29^A15:15:04.000^A150.00^A0^A0^A
```

Now I want to split this string as per the delim.

I tried this:

```
print "before ",line
line = line.split("\u001")
print "after ",line, type(line)


before  3710100008800☺2067400044☺2012-09-01☺09:10:05.000☺488.60☺0☺0☺
after  ['3710100008800\x012067400044\x012012-09-01\x0109:10:05.000\x01488.60\x010\x010\x01'] <type 'list'>
```

So first, I am on window machine...that smiley face in before should be ^A

So I do see that the type of line after splitting is a list

but its a weird list (has \x0 as delimeter??) and line[1] is not accessible so my guess is that its just the list of whole string.

All I want is to split this line as per this delimiter

Any clues?
Thanks

Comment: DId you try splitting on `'\x01'` instead of on `'\u001'`? You don't have a unicode string to begin with.